# Netty DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder set delimeter to '\r' only

Tags: netty

How do i get netty to take care to buffer the data until it receive a Delimiter ('\r' only!), i.e it must ignore '\r\n', and then dispatch it to the next handlers in the ChannelPipeline.
Can it be done with DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to write your own Decoder which should extend FrameDecoder. Just checkout the javadocs for FrameDecoder to get an idea howto implement it

Comment: public class IntegerHeaderFrameDecoder extends FrameDecoder {

   @Override
   protected Object decode(ChannelHandlerContext ctx,
                           channel,
                           ChannelBuffer buf) throws Exception {